# SQL Server agent,ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, agent

Can we use SQL Server Agent local system account to run SSIS packages that make use of files in FTP folders, or do we have access or permission error?

I am able to run SSIS packages only some, not for all.

My ssis packages picking files from some ftp locations and not from all.I may require some permission for the remaining ftp locations.

Thanks,
Priyanka Singh

Comment: Are the packages using FTP Task to download files from an FTP site?

Comment: You need to edit your question and include (1) the specific error you are getting and (2) the difference between the FTP packages that work and those that don't. That said, once you have done (2) you will probably have answered the question yourself!

Comment: I'm not aware of any FTP clients that use windows credentials to connect. So the agent account is probably irrelevant to connect. You do need to put the file somewhere once you download it so your account needs local write permissions somewhere. How about you try it and see.